# Contract Not sending ether to other account

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, metamask

I have created a contract which store the address of the users and i want to send 1 ether all the users stored in array.

Here is my code

```
contract project{

    address public user;
    bytes32[10] name;
    address[10] customer;
    uint public i=0;
    function project(){
        user=msg.sender;
    }



    function add(bytes32 _name){
        name[i]=_name;
        customer[i]=msg.sender;
        i++;
    }

    function get_address() constant returns(address[10]){
        return customer;
    }

    function reward() {
        for(uint i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            customer[i].send(1);
        }

    }

}
```

When i call the method reward metamask executed the transaction but ether is not transferred.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to make the contract send funds it doesn't have. It needs ether to draw from. The balance would start at 0, so you need to add a `function() payable{}` and send some ether to work with.

I've marked a section of the code `*** unsafe ***` to avoid misunderstanding. There are deeper concerns about handling money this way. A good next step is to check the success/fail of the `send()` operation and then respond differently. I have it emitting a failure message or a success message.

I added some event emitters so you can see what's going on.

Hope it helps.

```
contract project{

  address public user;
  bytes32[10] name;
  address[10] customer;
  uint public i=0;

  event LogDep (address sender,    uint amount, uint balance);
  event LogSent(address recipient, uint amount, uint balance);
  event LogErr (address recipient, uint amount, uint balance);

  function project(){
    user=msg.sender;
  }

  function depositFunds() public payable returns(bool success) {
    LogDep(msg.sender, msg.value, this.balance); 
    return true;
  }

  function add(bytes32 _name){
    name[i]=_name;
    customer[i]=msg.sender;
    i++;
  }

  function get_address() constant returns(address[10]){
    return customer;
  }

  function reward() {
    for(uint i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

        // *** unsafe pattern ***

        if(customer[i].send(1)) {
            LogSent(customer[i], 1, this.balance);
        } else {
            LogErr(customer[i], 1, this.balance);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here it is in Remix to show it working.

If you haven't seen Remix before, go here https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity and just paste the code into the compiler. You can interact with the contract functions.

Step 1: Create the contract

[image]

Step 2: Send the contract some funds

10 wei is just enough to send 1 to all 10 customers. If you send less, you'll start seeing failed sends in Step 3.

[image]

[image]

Step 3: send txn to reward()

**Be sure** to NOT send wei/eth this time, because this function isn't payable.

[image]

Comment: It is showing LogErr when I call reward. Can you tell me how can I send ether from one address to another?

Comment: Added some screen caps to my original answer. Not sure you've used Remix before. It's worth it.

Comment: You have the options of voting or accepting (or both) if the answer is helpful. ;-) Thanks.

Comment: So what you saying that if we want to send ether to other account we have to send ether to the contract. And then use send function.

Comment: Yes. The contract can't spend any funds except its own. So, you can make a convincingly honest contract with an obvious function. Then, users can trust the contract to perform its function with their funds. It's not possible to make a contract that spends from another party's account.

Comment: Great! I realize it's early explorations. Just to help you out, this explains the concerns about the "unsafe pattern". May not be clear at this stage, but it will helpful in time: https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices/#favor-pull-over-push-payments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56337/discussion-between-anurag-verma-and-rob-hitchens).