# Import contract wallet

Tags: ether, wallets, import

I am trying to import a contract wallet after having deleted all the data from my laptop.

I have the keystore file so I am able to recover my main account (in theory this should give me access to the contract wallet) but when I try to import the contract wallet I get something like: "You do not own the contract...you can add it as watch only".

However, when I add the contract as watch-only and try to interact with it (execute) nothing happens.

Complete novice here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you all

R

Answer (score 0):

First you need to run mist on computer B and import your wallet keystore file.
Second, To import a contract you need to go into the mist and click **contracts**-->**watch contract**, Then you need to give your **contract address**, **contract Name** and paste the **json code** in the **json interface** and click **ok**. See below:[image: Import contract]

Will update on how to interact with the contract soon. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Kishore, thank you for your reply. I can do it up to the point where I have the following options: "write to contract: remove owner, is owner, etc". My main doubt is how to go from here to having the funds of this wallet back in my main account. many thanks in advance. R

Comment: Hi again @Kishore . Don't know if you are able to help me further. As a sign of appreciation, I can sendo you some ether if you help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Refer these answers,  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19080/is-it-possible-to-send-ether-from-contract-address-to-my-account-address-using-t and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13722/contract-not-sending-ether-to-other-account.

Thank you

Comment: hi @rukyhh If you have access to the contract, Does the contract shows the Ether balance and is there a send option in that contract wallet?. Basically, to send ether from contracts is similar to sending ether from accounts only thing is that the transaction fee is higher. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Kishore. I can indeed watch the contract and see it's balance. 

Then I have "write to contract" option as following:

https://i.imgur.com/tRJrmIV.png

Comment: You need to access the contract with the same account that owns the contract. You can have many accounts, but only the owner will be able to interact with it. I believe in Mist, once you add the contract, you can click on the icon on the left bar to Authorize specific accounts. Do that with the correct account and try again.